# How to check video loading in a URL?

Tags: java, selenium, video, selenium-webdriver

I have a URL with a video embedded to it just like youtube URLs and i want to validate if the video loads and streams
The difficulty i am having is that i don't have the tagname , id or anything of the video element , so how can i check in such a case

Code using selenium:

```
public class URLCheck
{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  File file = new File("C:\\Users\\MB0000038\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
  WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtsrtcagbOQ");  
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  // JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  // WebElement video = driver.findElement(By.tagName("video"));
  driver.quit();

  }
}
```

This code works well but only open a chrome tab displaying the video

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your video, there are two tags which you can play around to verify your video.

```
       driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59rEMnKWoS4");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();    
        WebElement pauseAndPlay = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='ytp-play-button ytp-button']"));
        //Get the attribute aria-lable of pauseAndPlay Element which would tells you current state of video(pause/play)
       String videoState=pauseAndPlay.getAttribute("aria-label");
      if(videoState.equalsIgnoreCase("Pause")){
           System.out.println("Video is currently in play state");
           Thread.sleep(3000);
           //pausing my video and checking the current play time
            pauseAndPlay.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
           WebElement currentTimeElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-current']"));
            String currentTime=currentTimeElement.getText();
         if(currentTime!="0:00"){
             System.out.println("my video is getting progressed and currently at:"+currentTime);
          }else{
              System.out.println("my video is not getting played");
          }
    }else if(videoState.equalsIgnoreCase("Play")){

           System.out.println("Video is currently paused");

      }
```